# Downloaded 6.1sdk yesterday now [self.tabBarController presentViewController:... does not work

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I upgraded to x code 4.6 SDK 6.1 and now

```
[self.tabBarController presentViewController:loginViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

is Threading out.

This code worked with 6.0 on 6.0 and below simulators but now 6.0 and 6.1 crash while 5.1 and below simulators still run fine.

Basically in my app delecate i call a tab bar then run a login screen ontop of that till its dismissed.

[image]

EDIT: I am not using AutoLayout anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Got it I was under the impression that adding ~iPad/~iPhone to my xib name would work for a universial app in choosing which xib to use automatically.  Well on the 5.1 simulators it does however on 6 and above it does not.

so here is the correct code.

```
LoginViewController *loginViewController;
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController~iPhone" bundle:nil];
} else {
    viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController~iPad" bundle:nil];
}
```